# Mockito thenReturn is returning null

Tags: java, mockito

I've been wrestling with this for a while, and as a Java and Mockito newbie, I'm hoping it's a similar stupid mistake.

I have a method that looks like

```
public WrapperObject<Void> myMethod(...) {
    WrapperObject<Object1> o1 = getObject1FromWebServiceAndWrapIt(buildVar1(a));

    ...

    private buildVar1(a) {
        return someVar;
    }
}

@Test
public void testMyMethod() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(getObject1FromWebServiceAndWrapIt(MOCK_VAR1, MOCK_VAR2)).thenReturn(WrapperObject.of(MOCK_o1));
    ...
}
```

Even in this *simple* case, where I expect o1 to have the value MOCK_o1, it instead resolves as `null`.

I have tried the `Mockito.doReturn().when()` pattern, and that also fails to return anything but null.

I'm sorry for the brief code example, but it's in the middle of a bunch of junk and it would be hard to just paste the whole thing here. Does anyone recognize some horrible patterns going on?

Comment: Do your objects properly implement `equals`?

Comment: @Mureinik yes, they do.

Comment: Could you please post a complete example so that I can understand the problem? The current code looks like you are not passing the mock-object to Mockito.when().

Comment: This method getObject1FromWebServiceAndWrapIt is it static method or what. when you use when you mock the answer of the a method of a mocked object. So if the class that has this methos getObject1FromWebServiceAndWrapIt is Class1 then you need to do . Class1 obj = mock(Class1.class); then do (when.obj.getObject1FromWebServiceAndWrapIt(...)).thenReturn(..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was poorly phrased, however, the answer is rather independent of the question.

The issue ended up having to do with the fact that `Mockito.any()`, does *not* mock `varargs` appropriately. I was using a method that required a mock object of `varargs` to be passed.

You can rectify this by using `Mockito.anyVararg()`.